# perf lock <...> for non-root user?

Tags: perf

root can run `perf lock record`, whereas non-root can't:

```
$ /code/linux/tools/perf/perf lock record true
tracepoint lock:lock_acquire is not enabled. Are CONFIG_LOCKDEP and CONFIG_LOCK_STAT enabled?
```

Root:

```
$ sudo /code/linux/tools/perf/perf lock record true
[ perf record: Woken up 1 times to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 0.536 MB perf.data (5085 samples) ]
```

This is a command I'd rather not run as root (a complex build system); how can I allow running `perf lock <...>` as a non-root user?

For the record, `perf stat` works fine as a regular user.

Comment: `perf stat` and `perf lock` work differently. `perf lock` uses the [event tracing](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.18/trace/events.html) capability the kernel provides on [`debugfs`](https://docs.kernel.org/filesystems/debugfs.html) (`/sys/kernel/debug/tracing`). Both`/sys/kernel/debug` and `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing` are [not accessible by non-root users](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5914171).